# Convert string received in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, converters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

I get a string like this

```
 [["1","Pagamento de Placa","N","N"], ["2,""Contrato","N","N"], ["3","Ajuste de preço","N","N"],["4", "Abertura de cliente","N","N"], ["9","Outros","N","S"]]
```

I try

```
 var arr = new Array([["1","Pagamento de Placa","N","N"], ["2,""Contrato","N","N"], ["3","Ajuste de preço","N","N"],["4", "Abertura de cliente","N","N"], ["9","Outros","N","S"]]);
```

but not work

I want to turn into a real array, any idea how to do?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, the whole line is a string?

Comment: JSON.parse() should do that for you.

Comment: yes, the line is string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var arrayString = '[["1","Pagamento de Placa","N","N"], ["2,"Contrato","N","N"], ["3","Ajuste de preço","N","N"],["4", "Abertura de cliente","N","N"], ["9","Outros","N","S"]]';
var array = JSON.parse(arrayString);
```

(There's a duplicate `"` in the original string - I removed it.)

If you need to support older browsers use a library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: The first element of the second element of the parent array is missing a quote or has one too many.